# need a dmscookie code for every language in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cookies

For a client's site in wordpress we're using dms cookie. Since every language is on a different domain, we tough about a script to  show a dms cookie script based on the language. So I figured something like that:

```
<?php
oxides_edge_get_header();
if( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en' ) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript' charset='UTF-8'
src='https:engscript.js'>
</script>";
} else if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'it' ) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript' charset='UTF-8'
src='https://itascript.js'>
</script>";
} else if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'de' ) {
 echo "<script type='text/javascript' charset='UTF-8'
src='https://germanscript.js'>
</script>";
} else if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr' ) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript' charset='UTF-8' 
src='https://frenchscript.js'>
</script>";
}
?>
```

But it's not working

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
<?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'); ?>
<script type='text/javascript' charset='UTF-8' src='https://engscript.js'></script>
<?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it'); ?>
<script type='text/javascript' charset='UTF-8' src='https://itascript.js'></script>
<?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='de'); ?>
<script type='text/javascript' charset='UTF-8' src='https://germanscript.js'></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```